# Resigning while in Probationary Period

Tags: resignation, probation, philippines

I'm from Philippines. I would like to ask if those under probationary period should give 30 days notice before resigning? I have checked my contract and it says that 'to give 30 days notice to those employees on probation'.
Or can I at least give 2-3 weeks notice? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If your contract says Give 30 days notice. Then you give 30 days notice.

That was your agreement when joining.

Also by law you are required the 30 days also as shown [Here](https://www.jobstreet.com.ph/career-resources/preparing-resign-counting-last-days-job#.XERzzh2zPJE)